# When to use headless activity and service in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am working on an android device where configuration change is *not* going to happen. In this case I have few units of work that I want to delegate to a particular Android entity. The work does not involve UI. Should I delegate this non-UI work to a service OR a headless activity?

In other words, what are the benefits of headless activity as compared to a service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) to schedule your tasks.

Otherwise, I would suggest you use a foreground service.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a service. It runs in the background, user can do other things, until the service finishes.